How to make JS code retrieve data from an org-table?
Suppose the following org file:
#+name: data-input
|------------+------|
|       Date |   Kg |
|------------+------|
| 2024-08-03 | 74.9 |
| 2024-08-04 | 75.3 |
| 2024-08-05 | 74.4 |
| 2024-08-06 | 74.1 |
| 2024-08-07 | 73.2 |
| 2024-08-08 | 72.8 |
| 2024-08-09 | 71.9 |
|------------+------|

#+begin_export html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.34.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
#+end_export
#+begin_export html
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
#+end_export
#+begin_export html
<script>
TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [{
x: [ '2024-08-03' , '2024-08-04' , '2024-08-05' , '2024-08-06' , '2024-08-07' , '2024-08-08' , '2024-08-09'],
y: [ 74.9 , 75.3 , 74.4 , 74.1 , 73.2 , 72.8 , 71.9] }], {
margin: { t: 0 } } );
</script>
#+end_export

C-c C-e ho will open a page with a table and a nice chart.
How could I have org-mode feed x vector with Date and y vector with Kg?

There are two keys to this solution.
The first is to write a source block that produces the desired output (in this case, the whole text of the last export block, including the #+begin/end_export). The idea is that the exporter will execute the source block which will produce the export block and which the exporter will then export. You can write the block in any language you want - here's a python version:
#+begin_src python  :results output drawer :exports results :var x="[1, 2, 3]"  :var y="[1, 8, 27]"
  print("#+begin_export html")
  print("<script>")
  print("TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');")
  print("Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [{")
  print("x: %s," % (x))
  print("y: %s }], {" % (y))
  print("margin: { t: 0 } } );")
  print("</script>")
  print("#+end_export")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
#+begin_export html
<script>
TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [{
x: [1, 2, 3],
y: [1, 8, 27] }], {
margin: { t: 0 } } );
</script>
#+end_export
:end:


If you delete the third export block from your Org mode file and instead, insert the source block and export, you'll get a stupid little graph that has nothing to do with your table; but the important thing is that the source block is run, it produces a result block that contains an (almost) exact copy of your third export block and that is processed properly to produce a graph - not the graph you want, but we'll fix that next.
Note the header line: we use :exports results to make sure that the code is not exported but the results are exported; and we pass (bogus) values for x and y that affect the graph.
The second key is to pass the correct values for x and y. These values should come from the table. How to do that is described in the section Environment of a Source Block in the Org mode manual: the first subsection is entitled Passing Arguments and towards the end of that subsection (starting with literal example, or code block contents), it describes how to pass portions of a variable. For example, the whole column 1 of your table can be passed as data-input[,0] or data-input[*,0] or data-input[0:-1,0] - all of these are read as all the rows of column 1 of data-input. Note that indices are 0-based, not 1-based, as they are in table formulas, and negative indices count from the end (like Python lists). In your case, you don't want the whole column: you need to skip the first two rows (the header and the hline) so you want to say data-input[2:-1,0] for the date column and data-input[2:-1,1] for the weight column. So the code block should look like this:
#+begin_src python  :results output drawer :exports results :var x=data-input[2:-1,0]  :var y=data-input[2:-1,1]
  print("#+begin_export html")
  print("<script>")
  print("TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');")
  print("Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [{")
  print("x: %s," % (x))
  print("y: %s }], {" % (y))
  print("margin: { t: 0 } } );")
  print("</script>")
  print("#+end_export")
#+end_src


Now export with C-c C-e ho and you'll get a graph based on the table.
